How to abort a parallel computation?
This is a minimal working example. I have a computation that runs in parallel for ever, and now and then prints a result.
ParallelEvaluate[ While[True, Pause[RandomReal[{0,100}]]; Print[$KernelID]]]

When I am satisfied with the printed results, I want to abort the evaluation. Of course I can use Alt-dot, and in this example it works fine, but in my application by no means always. When it did not work, the only thing I still could do was to kill and restart the kernel. Therefore, I am looking for a better way of aborting the parallel computation manually. Since it is running, I can only stop it by using a button, that will execute my command over the preemptive link.  This is the button that almost does the job:
Button["Abort Kernels", AbortKernels[] ]

It does not always stop the parallel evaluation immediately, but with a second or third click the parallel computation has stopped without crashing Mathematica. However, some mysterious error messages turn up:
ParallelKernelsreceive::nothing: No pending evaluation on KernelObject[<|Context->EvaluatorsLocalKernels, ...
So I have two questions: what do these error messages mean, and more general, what is the best way of aborting a parallel computation that intentionally runs forever?

In which cases does abort not work? Can you make a simple example? Note that functions differ in how often they listen for the abort signals, which is actually a good thing because this increases their performance.

@Domen Unfortunately I cannot give a simple example. The function that I actually use in ParallelEvaluate is pretty complicated. Alt-dot works only rarely. However,  I cannot exclude that I was to impatient. Anyway, I am looking for better ways of doing. The button with AbortKernels works considarable better, but with error messages that I do not understand.

What happens if you run this function on a single kernel, without parallelization? Can you abort it via Alt-.?

Yes, no problem. By the way, if you first evaluate the button, then run the ParallelEvaluate and then press the button as in my question, you will see the error messages.
